# Regex to catch that string contains alphanumeric, underscore and space, but start with letter

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex alphanumeric, underscore and space, but only allowed to start with a letter.
I am having this input that checks if the typed characters are matching the allowed chars, which works fine.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="topic"
placeholder="Enter topic name" name="topic"
onkeypress="return /^[_ a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(event.key)" required>
```

But If I try to make sure that the first chars is a letter it doesn't work

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="topic"
placeholder="Enter topic name" name="topic"
onkeypress="return /^[a-zA-Z][_ a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(event.key)" required>
```

It basically block the whole field. I can see what I am doing wrong

Comment: `onkeypress` checks the currently pressed key value, not the whole input value. You should probably just use `pattern="[a-zA-Z][\w ]*"` for on-submit validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wiktor Stribizew mentioned in his comment, your code is only validating the currently pressed key value. But an alternative to the on-submit validation is using  an `onkeyup` handler, which has its pluses and minuses, which happen to be the same, namely that when this event occurs the input field has been potentially modified with new content. The minus is that if an illegal character has been entered, it will momentarily show in the field before it is removed. The plus is that no keystroke analysis is required.

```js
function setupField(field, re)
{
    field.autocomplete = "off";
    field.saveValue = field.value;
    field.onkeyup = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (v === '' || re.test(v)) {
            field.saveValue = v;
        }
        else {
            field.value = field.saveValue;
        }
    };
}

let topic = document.getElementById('topic');
setupField(topic, /^[a-z][a-z0-9_ ]*$/i);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="topic" placeholder="Enter topic name" name="topic" required>
```

Comment: Thanks, Booboo. That did the trick. I didn't know that it is actually looking at the current character and not the whole value